# Converting parameters when passing to functions (c++)

Tags: c++, variables, parameter-passing, variable-types

I am just starting to teach myself C++ and am having a hard time with function parameter passing. For example I am using my own print function where you simply put the string into the parameters and it logs it to the console.

```
//Print Function
void print(std::string message = "") {
    std::cout << message << std::endl;
}
```

However because I declare it as a `std::string` variable if I pass it a number it will not print it. Ultimately I would like to make an input and print system like in Python. How to I go about this? Is there a way to convert the parameters to string? Or some other solution. Another function with similar problems is my input function:

```
//Input function (Enter does not work without text, space is not text)
std::string input(const char* message = "") {
    std::cout << message;
    std::string x;
    std::cin >> x;
    return x;
}
```

This does not allow the return to be an int witch makes calculations using the input harder. Any help is appreciated thanks in advance!

~ Moses

Comment: Using template might be what you want

Comment: Where might I find further help on this? I do not know what a template is.

Comment: @Mose I would suggest you stay out of templates till you get grasp of C++.

Comment: If you're dealing with limited parameter types, function overloading is an option.

Comment: Just call your function with `std::to_string(4)` for example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Besides `template`, if your compiler supports C++14, You can also use `auto` with lambda function. You can just write all these inside the main function.

```
auto print = [](const auto& message) {std::cout << message << std::endl;};
print(1); //1
print("AAA"); //AAA
```

Note that, unlike Python, when you want to print something, you don't need to convert it to a `string` first. As long as the thing you want to print has overloaded `cout`, You can simply `cout` it. And using `template` or `auto` doesn't change the fact that everything in C++ is statically typed, it's just that the compiler will create the different versions of overload functions for you automatically.

**EDIT**
As @Peter pointed out in the comment section, saying "`cout` is something that can be overloaded is flat-out wrong", and more accurate to say overloading the `operator<<` for the `ostream` and the corresponding class

Comment: What do you mean by overload? So auto is used in replacement for "void, int, const char, std::string" and those identifiers. Could you explain why you are doing what you are doing here? `auto print = [](const auto& message)` Thanks, this seems to be a handy tool!

Comment: function overload means functions with the same name but different types/numbers of parameters. In this case, the compiler generate print(int) and print(char*) for you. If you do not use template/auto, you'd need to write both functions yourself.

Comment: `auto print = [](const auto& message)` This is a new C++ syntax called lambda expression. It's basically the same as a global function, but can be handy to write.

Comment: Thank you very much! Ill go watch some videos on lambda and auto. Great answer

Comment: `[]` tells the compiler that I'm about to declare a lambda expression. `(const auto& message)` is like the function parameters. I use `const auto&` --accept a reference because it's more efficient than `auto`-- make a copy. `=` to store the lambda expression in the variable print so we can use it later on!

Comment: Must I use `= []` or can I just run the `(const auto& message)` expression?

Comment: :) sure you can do that. And this will be a free function, not a lambda function. So you'd need to write it outside of the main function.

Comment: If you use lambda expression, there are two ways to call it. One is like what I wrote in my answer, another way would be kind of long -- `[](const auto& message) {std::cout << message << std::endl;}("AAA")`

Comment: If lambda is confusing, what you mentioned before is perfectly valid -- use `auto print(const auto& message) { std::cout << message << std::endl; };` outside of the main, this is essentially a free function with auto used in parameter and return type!

Comment: And make sure your compiler supports C++14 :)

Comment: `cout` is an object.   It is not something that can be overloaded.   It is of a type (`std::ostream`) for which a set of overloaded functions, including `operator<<()`, are supplied.    But to say `cout` is something that can be overloaded is flat-out wrong.

Comment: @Peter thanks for the clarification! Yeah, I shouldn't say overload cout... more accurate to say overload operator << for the ostream and the corresponding class/type

Answer (score 0):

Can++ templates are useful there.

```
//Print Function
template <typename T>
void print(const T& message) {
  std::cout << message << std::endl;
}

void print() {
  std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

Note, I removed a default argument value and used overloaded function. With passed empty argument type of template parameter can not be deduced. `print` does not work with containers and you need more efforts to print containers, in Python it works from box.

```
//Input function (Enter does not work without text, space is not text)
template <typename T>
T input(const char* message = "") 
{
  std::cout << message;
  T x;
  std::cin >> x;
  return x;
}
```

Usage: `int n = input<int>("Input number:");`.

Comment: Thanks! Ill look into templates :)

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively I discovered a way to do this without using lambda:

```
void print(int message) {
    std::cout << message << std::endl;
};

void print(float message) {
    std::cout << message << std::endl;
};

void print(std::string message) {
    std::cout << message << std::endl;
};
```

By making multiple functions with the same name it will use what ever one works, so any input (3.14, 8, "Hello") will all work and use corresponding function.